# Get parameter from url asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, url-parameters

I want to get the parameter from a url as below:

```
www.domain.com/Controller/Action/Parameter
```

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    //some codes
}
```

User enters url as above and should navigate the the specific controller. How do I get the 'Parameter' in the Action of my controller?

Comment: Change you method to include a parameter - e.g. `public ActionResult Action(string id)` assuming your using the default route (in your example, the value of `id` will be `"Parameter"`)

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 things:
1) add parameter to your action, ie:
Action(string param, ...)

2) configure the routing to tell mvc how to map route data to parameters.
Default mvc route is configured to map /## to "id" parameter, but you can add more routes to map other parameters as you need. For example add this line to your App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file:

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "CustomRoute",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{param}
            );

note that "{param}" match the name of your action parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    string param1 = this.Request.QueryString["param"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When someone enter url like the example above, you can do this to get the segment value in your controller.

URL: www.domain.com/Controller/Action/Parameter

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    string parameter = this.Request.Url.Segments[segmentIndex];
    //The segmentIndex in the url above should be 3 
}
```